# IPV6-Problems: [registerService] Failed to contact master at [server:11311]. Retrying

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heyho, somehow using

```
export ROS_IPV6=on
```

in Docker doesn't work and gives the error message in the title: `[registerService] Failed to contact master at [server:11311].  Retrying...`

ROS-Version: Melodic
Host System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Docker-Version: 20.10.12

Steps to reproduce:

```
docker pull osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full
docker run -it --rm --net=host osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full /bin/bash
export ROS_IPV6=on
roscore
```

Output:

```
... logging to /root/.ros/log/2bae647e-7251-11ec-85b6-b42e99464746/roslaunch-server-35.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://server:46123/
ros_comm version 1.14.11


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.11

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [45]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://server:11311/

setting /run_id to 2bae647e-7251-11ec-85b6-b42e99464746
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [56]
started core service [/rosout]
[ERROR] [1641845350.101209283]: [registerService] Failed to contact master at [server:11311].  Retrying...
```

Any pointers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394027/ipv6-problems:-%5Bregisterservice%5D-failed-to-contact-master-at-%5Bserver:11311%5D.--retrying.../) by [Raph](https://answers.ros.org/users/93218/raph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raph](https://answers.ros.org/users/93218/raph/) on 2022-01-10**:
Just tried directly on a pc, it shows the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the solution: You also need to set ROS_HOSTNAME to the correct one with export ROS_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME

---

Originally posted by [Raph](https://answers.ros.org/users/93218/raph/) with karma: 16 on 2022-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0